# Stored procedure for finding score up until given date

Tags: mysql, sql

edit: owngoals are goals made by the team total. Othergoals are goals made by other team total

I have 2 tables, a TEAMS and MATCHES table.

```
create table teams                                                                                                   
(                                                                                                                                  
Id char(3) primary key,                                                                                                  
name varchar(40),                                                                                                                   
nomatches int,                                                                                                                      
owngoals int,                                                                                                      
othergoals int,                                                                                                                  
points int                                                                                                                    
)
```

and

```
create table matches                                                                                                     
(                                                                                                                                    
id int identity(1,1),                                                                                            
homeid char(3) foreign key references teams(id),                                                                 
outid char(3) foreign key references teams(id),                                                                    
homegoal int,                                                                                                                     
outgoal int,                                                                                                                           
matchdate date                                                                                                               
)
```

i have triggers for inserting and deleting that gives the correct score for the teams.
the select to show the scoreboard looks like this.

```
select name, nomatches, owngoals, othergoals, points from teams 
order by points desc
```

and it will give this result, with the numbers being Number of matches, goals made by team, goals made against you, total points

[image]

Now i need to make a stored procedure that makes the scoreboard but only until a given date. I have tried some different stuff like making a copy of the Teams table as a @tmpTeams, but nothing has worked.

Comment: You need to drive by matches..storing match statistics in teams is not a good idea and I don't know how you could distinguish own goals from the data provided in matches, and what does other goals mean , what abouts goal scored at home , goals scored away from home, own goals at home own goals away..Penalties..

Comment: Select only rows which matches the condition by date from `matches` table. Group by a command and calculate needed statistic with according aggregate function. Ignore current statistic data from `teams` table.

Comment: the tables were given to me and im not allowed to modify them, so i assume it is possible with what i was given. I realize the names are not easy to understand. Owngoals is goals scored in a match and in the teams table it is just total goals for all matches.

Comment: Own goal has a very specific meaning in football - where the naming conventions are ambiguous/ inconsistant you should  clarify by explanation.

Comment: so i've figured i will try with a cursor and run through all matches and then insert the results into a temporary declared Teams table.

Comment: @hosdal
I've created procedure with all the information i got but there is still an issue about own goal calculation , other goals & points 
https://pastebin.com/5Kk2pTt1

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want an aggregation query?  Your question doesn't explain what the logic is for the columns, but I'm guessing something like this:

```
select t.id, t.name,
       sum(mh.homegoal) as homegoals,
       sum(mo.outgoal) as othergoals,
       coalesce(sum(mh.homegoal), 0) + coalesce(sum(mo.outgoal), 0) as totalpoints
kfrom teams t left join
     matches mh
     on mh.homeid = t.id and
        mh.matchdate >= ? left join
     matches mo
     on mo.outid = t.id and
        mo.matchdate >= ?
group by t.id, t.name;
```

The `?` is intended to be a parameter for your date.

Note:  I seen no reason to have triggers when this information can be calculated using a query -- unless you have a performance issue that requires triggers to solve.